# How can I make a std::vector of function pointers?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, stdvector

I have seen some similar questions but I can't get this to work.

This fails:

```
std::vector<void (CChristianLifeMinistryEntry::* pfnSetAssignName)(CString)> = xx;
```

I want a vector so that I can pre-fill it with a series of `&CChristianLifeMinistryEntry::SetXXX` functions. This is so that I can quickly determine the right function to use in a `for` loop I have.

Comment: What is the problem you have? Can you please try to create a [mre] to show us, and describe the problems you have with getting it to work? Include build errors if you get any.

Comment: A pointer to a non-static member function is not the same thing as a function pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
std::vector<void (CChristianLifeMinistryEntry::*)(CString)> pfnSetAssignName = xx;
```

Comment: This answer was spot on. Thank you very much. Such a simple solution!!!!

Comment: Vote for the concise.